# If someone from Xbox joins my Pocket Edition world, will they see my textures?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a bunch of minor texture packs on my MineCraft PE world, such as no carved faces on natural pumpkins. I also made it so anybody joining my world must accept the texture packs. If someone from Xbox One joins my world, will they see the world textures?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you can join a Minecraft world on Xbox from PE, and vice versa with the new better together update. Furthermore, I tested it out and answered my own question: Yes, the texture packs WILL show up. Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: If you'll add a source to this, I'll remove my apparently incorrect answer.

Comment: This should help: https://minecraft.net/en-us/article/better-together-update-here , but at the time of that article Xbox One was not supported yet. This article should also be helpful: https://support.xbox.com/en-US/games/game-titles/minecraft-better-together-update and https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Better_Together_Update and https://minecraft.net/en-us/article/better-together-faq